# Как сконвертировать byte[] с бэкенда в img на странице

Tags: javascript, java, angular, img

На бэкенде на java из БД вытягиваются данные по книге:

```
public class Book {

private Integer id;
private String author;
private String title;
private String description;
private byte[] cover;

constructors, getters and setters
}
```

вот так достаётся изображение :

```
Blob fileCover = rs.getBlob(Constants.KEY_COVER);
                if(fileCover != null) {
                 cover = fileCover.getBytes(1,(int)fileCover.length());
                }
```

и сервлетом отправляется на ангуляр

```
 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id = request.getParameter(Constants.KEY_ID);
    Book fullBook = getBookDAO().getFullBook(Integer.parseInt(id));

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    mapper.writeValue(writer, fullBook);
}
```

вот класс на ангуляр

```
export class Book {
  description: string;
  cover: ???(пробовала Blob, string, ImageData);

  constructor(public id: number,
              public author: string,
              public title: string) {
  }

}
```

пытаюсь вывести на страницу таким образом

```
 <img *ngIf="book.cover" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{book.cover}}"/>
```

Но что-то очевидно не так и картинка не отображается, а лишь

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,LS0tLS0tV2ViS2l0Rm9ybUJvdW5kYXJ5aDhsd1l4TXZYejFZNTh5UA0KQ29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJmaWxlIjsgZmlsZW5hbWU9IkJyYXZlTmV3V29ybGQuanBnIg0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBpbWFnZS9qcGVnDQoNCsO...">
```

Очевидно это не преобразовывается в Base64 или делает это не правильно, вопрос как это поправить??

Comment: Посмотрите, какие данные приходят с сервера с помощью DevTools.

Comment: {"id":4,"author":"Homer","title":"The Odyssey","description":"The Odyssey is one of two major ancient Greek epic poems attributed to Homer. It is, in part, a sequel to the Iliad, the other work traditionally ascribed to Homer.","cover":"TFMwdExTMHRWMlZpUzJsMFJtOXliVUp2ZFc1a1lYSjVVR056VDI1Wm...waHNRa290TFEwSw=="}   вот такой респонс

Comment: Ну, видно, что это base64 строка. Вы уверены, что она jpg? Добавьте полный респонс в ваш вопрос.

Comment: Либо это не base64, либо в нем завернута не jpeg картинка, потому что при декодировании первые 6 байт 0x2d, а jpeg на FF D8 FF начинаются. Та строка что в комментарии то же на jpeg не тянет

Comment: Mike спасибо, проверила и вправду это не  base64, но точно 100% jpeg, значит где-то или не кодируется или делает это не правильно(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён,выше написанный код весь верен, проблема была в том что данные по пути в БД отправлялись криво, в БД записывалась не сама картинка, а целая форма, соответственно и доставалось неверно